# Kestore availability in public

Tags: android, security, google-play, android-keystore

Today when I was signing my application I came across the various steps of creating key store file and assigning passwords to it. Since, I was doing it from the date I am working on android but today it came to my mind what are the possibilities in following scenarios:

1. If some one got my key store password but not the file itself?
2. If some one got my key store password with key store file and all the info?
3. If it effects on my application available on Google Store?
4. If some one has my application's package file with option 2?

Or any other drawback of keeping simple passwords for the key store file?

*I didn't include the knowing of Google play account credential any where in the points because this is for obvious that any one can do the up gradation of app then.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a secure password safe.  Let it generate a strong password.  Store the keyfile and the password in the safe then back it up.  I use Dashlane backed up local storage plus Sugarsync (because it's much more secure than Dropbox)

Answer (score 2):

> If some one got my key store password but not the file itself?

The person could do nothing with it.

> If some one got my key store password with key store file and all the info?

If the person has access to your google play developer account, then he/she can upload an update to your app. Either way he/she can sign an .apk and if someone, who has previously installed your app, installs it (through side loading or third party sources), then the app will get updated without any conflicts

> If it effects on my application available on Google Store?

If you loose your keystore then you can't update the app you signed with it on the play store, so always keep it backuped.

> Or any other drawback of keeping simple passwords for the key store file?

Like already said, nothing can happen as long as nobody gets access to your keystore.

Comment: Obviously the person should have my Google Play credentials to update an application thats why I didn't include it in any point bcz I know we can do so. see my edited question..